# how to run group of tasks in parallel?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow-2.x

I've a one task group, named as `tasks`, in that task group I can have dynamic number of tasks

as of now, I'm running all tasks in seq, by setting dependency like this

```
   taskList.append(tg)
   if len(taskList) > 1:
      taskList[i-1] >> taskList[i]
```

This will run all tasks in sequence, Is there any way I could run in `n` multiple of total tasks (`total`) in parallel ?

For example, I've I've total 10 tasks and I want to run multiple of 3

```
1st exec ..will run task 1, 2, 3 in parallel
2nd exec ..will run task 4,5,6 in parallel
3rd exec .. will run 7,8,9 in parallel
4th exec ..will run 10th task alone
```

Is there any way I could set up dependencies like this ?

Thanks